# Why does the CPU profile in Visual vm show the process spends all its time in a promise deref when using clojure's core async to read a kafka stream

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka

I am running a clojure app reading from a kaka stream. I am using the shovel github project https://github.com/l1x/shovel to read from a kafka stream. When I profiled my application using visual vm looking for hotspots I noticed that most of the cpu time about 70% is being spent in the function clojure.core$promise$reify__6310.deref.

The shovel api consumer is a thinwrapper on the Kafka consumergroup api. It reads from a kafka topic and publishes out to a core async channel. Should i be concerned that my application latencies would be affected if i continued using this api. Is there any explanation why the reify on the promise is taking this much cpu time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Clojure, `$` is used in the printed representation of a class to represent an inner class. `clojure.core$promise$reify__6310.deref` means calling the method `deref` on a class that is created via `reify` as an inner class of `clojure.core/promise`. As it turns out, if you look at the class of a `promise`, it will show up as an inner reified class inside `clojure.core$promise`.

A `promise` in Clojure represents data that may not yet be available. You can see its behavior in a repl:

```
user> (def p (promise))
#'user/p
user> (class p)
clojure.core$promise$reify__6363
user> (deref p)
```

This will hang and give no result, and not give the next repl prompt, until you `deliver` to the promise from another repl connection, or interrupt the `deref` call. The fact that time is being spent on `deref` of a `promise` simply means that the program logic is waiting on values that are not yet computed (or have not yet come in via the network, etc.).

Comment: so in my case that really means there is no overhead because of this when i see this in a visual vm profile

Comment: any time spent on `deref` on a `promise` should be spent on an actual task that would `deliver` to that promise, so I think it would be best to look for patterns elsewhere, yeah